# ROW(A1) function producing string in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

I am writing some Google Apps Scripts for a spreadsheet that a friend has (that they used a template to get).  It's basically a Project Planner/Gantt Chart, so there's a top row that says JAN FEB MAR APR ... and so on, and the blocks underneath will be shaded if the task in the first column is taking place in that month.

The issue is coming when I try to use the spreadsheet function **ROW()** and I get back the string **"Jan"** in almost any box I reference.  The same happens for **COL()**.  I'm sure that the existing template that my friend used named a range (or something along those lines), but I can't figure out how to get rid of it.  I haven't been able to find any explanation as to why the result of either of these functions would be a string and not a number.

[image]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Also, whoever down-voted me, could you elaborate?  I'm stuck either way..if I could get some useful feedback, (whether it be how to re-word my question or give me an actual answer), it would really be appreciated.

Comment: No, doesn't look like it.

Comment: Just added an image, but don't have permission to attach entire spreadsheet.  I just want to see if anyone knows how this could possibly happen and send me in the right direction to fix it.

Comment: I think @pnuts is correct, it is the formatting. Select the cell with the formula in it, click Format, and change it to automatic.

Comment: Ok, you guys were right.  Sorry about the simple question.  I was just very stuck and I'd check the conditional formatting but not the actual formatting.  My mistake.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @pnuts Yes, I mean I didn't have permission from my friend.